# Customize embedded Mapbox navigation screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, navigation, mapbox

I'm trying to make a turn by turn navigation app with flutter but I have a problem. I am using the Mapbox navigation package and I want the navigation screen to remain in the screen where I called it, not to open another screen. I used embedded Mapbox navigation but I cant show voice instructions ,also I can't change the marker shows on map.  How can I customize the embedded Mapbox navigation widget.

Comment: Please present some code that shows what you've been trying so far.

Comment: Your question needs to be more specific and should include some code so we can better understand what you're actually trying to do.